# Flutter Spinkit Progress Indicator

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm a newbie in flutter and wanted to know what is the best way to add [Spinkit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit) to my current layout. For example, when I press on a button to connect with a webview on the next screen. Loading the webview currently takes between 2-4 seconds and I would like a progress indicator to appear. I would like to create an overlay layout (with Opacity) that finishes its animation when the webview has loaded.

Here is my current Webview code:

```
 class MyWebView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String selectedUrl;

  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  MyWebView({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.selectedUrl,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
//            Image.asset(
//              'assets/logo.png',
//              fit: BoxFit.contain,
//              height: 32,
//            ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 8.0, right: 64.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/White logo - no background.png',
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: WebView(
          initialUrl: selectedUrl,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

I understand that I need to insert the following code within my code but am unsure where and would also like to know how to work with including futures into this code:

```
    final spinkit = SpinKitSquareCircle(
  color: Colors.white,
  size: 50.0,
  controller: AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1200)),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a `bool isLoading` which detects whether Page is finished loading or not, based on that you can hide or show your SpinKitSquareCircle.

```
class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewPageState createState() => _WebViewPageState();
}

class _WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  bool isLoading = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com/',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onPageFinished: (String url) {
              setState(() {
                //hide you progressbar here
                isLoading = false;
              });
            },
          ),
          isLoading ? SpinKitSquareCircle(
            color: Colors.red,
            size: 50.0,
            controller: AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1200)),
          ) : Stack()
        ],
      ),);;
  }
}
```

You can find the code in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/9f511d155a446d4194bacb0a7fbb8a04) too.
Also if you just want to load gifs then you don't have to add [flutter_spinkit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit) library, load gif on Image.asset instead,

```
Image.asset(
                    "images/loading.gif",
                    height: 125.0,
                    width: 125.0,
                  )
```